# Can't run startx a non-root user in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, xfce

I've installed Kali Linux from a mini ISO network install on VirtualBox. I then installed xfce and ran `startx` on root account.

```
apt-get install xfce4
apt-get install xfce4-goodies
startx
```

xfce starts perfectly. I logged out from xfce. I then created a new user:

```
useradd everyone
passwd *******
mkdir /home/everyone
chown everyone:users /home/everyone
```

I log in with new user and `startx`:

```
exit
login: everyone
startx
```

When I run `startx` as another user than root, the screen blinks and goes back to the command line again. I tried XDM but when I switched the user, the issue persisted.

Comment: Do you have ~/.Xauthority file for you user? Also, why you are chowned home directory to this group?

Comment: Daniel, please familiarize yourself with our formatting options. There's no need to use HTML – and note that you need to indent code with 4 spaces. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`adduser` is a convenience script calling `useradd` with a few flags. If @Daniele is right than your issue either arise because your user doesn't have a shell assigned or it doesn't have a home directory assigned. Those two options can be corrected in `/etc/passwd` or by calling `usermod`. Also possible because you don't have a password assigned. That can be corrected by calling `passwd USERNAME` and can be checked in `/etc/shadow`. On the next user I suggest using the convenience script `adduser` or the appropriate flags, which are on the top of my head without checking and therefore not necessarily correct: `useradd -m -p -s /bin/bash USERNAME`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved using `adduser` instead of `useradd`.